# What scripture does the sloka 'deho devAlayaH proktaH..' come from?

Tags: identification-request, worship, shloka

> देहो देवालयः प्रोक्तः जीवो देवस्सनातनः । 
>  त्यजेदज्ञाननिर्माल्यं
> सोऽहं भावेन पूजयेत् ॥
>
> deho devAlayaH proktaH jIvo devassanAtanaH | 
> tyajed agnyAnana nirmAlyaM sohaM bhAvena pUjayet ||

Which scripture is the source of the above sloka?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it in the 2nd Adhyaya of [Maitreyi Upanishad](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/maitreyi.html?lang=sa):

> स होवाच महादेवः ॥
>
> देहो देवालयः प्रोक्तः स जीवः केवलः शिवः ।
>    त्यजेदज्ञाननिर्माल्यं सोऽहम्भावेन पूजयेत् ॥ १॥
>
> sa hovAcha mahAdevaH ||
>
> deho devAlayaH proktaH sa jIvaH kevalaH shivaH |
>   tyajedaj~nAnanirmAlyaM so.ahambhAvena pUjayet || 1||

Lord Shiva says this verse (Sa hovacha Mahadeva). It is the 1st verse of the 2nd chapter of the Upanishad.

Maitreyi Upanishad is a minor Upanishad linked with the Sama Veda (as per Muktika Upanishad's list). It is also known as [Maitreya Upanishad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maitreya_Upanishad).

NOTE: The verse I have given is almost matching with the verse you have given in the question. In my verse it is "Sa jivah kevala shivah" where as in your verse it is "Jivo devas sanatanah". This is the only difference.

Comment: Transliteration and translation please.

Comment: @Rickross your version doesn't match the question sa jiva kevala siva?? agnya is replaced by gnana?? why which one is interpolation

Comment: Sa jiva keval siva -- yes this part isn't matching, otherwise it is the the same verse .... I hv overlooked and no agyana is not replaced by gyana . otherwise the meaning would hv changed ... only a A-kara is missing that could be a typo nothing else @PrasannaR

Comment: @PrasannaR It's tyajet + Ajnana

Comment: @TheDestroyer What do u suggest here? The verse I hv given is almost matching with the Q but only slightly different..

Comment: @TheDestroyer I hv added a note as per ur suggestion..

Comment: @Rickross tyajed plus ajnana is tyajedajnan. so no missing of A-kara

Comment: Yes I missed I thought he missed Sandhi but not here @ParthaBanerjee

Answer (score 3):

The full sloka according to the Kularnavatantra is

देहो देवालयो देवि जीवो देवः सदाशिवः।
त्यजेदज्ञाननिर्माल्यं सोऽहंभावेन पूजयेत्॥ (9/41).

The last tw words of the first line reads 'devaH SadashivaH'.

'Sanatana' could be a pathantara. But according to the spirit of tantra, Sadhashiva seems apt.

Comment: When you are adding source of the shlokas or mantras, you should add transliteration of the mantra because everyone can't understand and read Devanagari and is limited to some users. There are many people who are from other states and countries on this site. This is an English language site. Many people can't understand what is written in the question or answer if only one script is added.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma the question asked the source alone

Comment: I know and looks like the verse is not the same as the one quoted in the question. You should use transliteration into standard transliteration scheme in case of finding source questions and where the verses play the major role. It is now in Devanagari which most of the people do not understand on the site. It is about understandability.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma how does the verse look different except one word?

Comment: That is my question. How can anyone who not even understand what is written in the answer whether the verse in the question and one in the answer or same or different? You should add English Transliteration for any non English language here because this is basically an English language site.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma only one word that is different has been mentioned. rest is the same and thats given in the question!

Comment: @parthabanerjee you need to give the transliteration and the link to where you got the text from. One word difference makes it different. And I see 2 differences. So why don't you just post your sources and the transliteration?